# How to get owl:sameas in dbpedia

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, wikidata, linked-data

I am using the following query to get wikidata ID from dbpedia page using `owl:sameas`.

```
SELECT distinct ?wikidata_concept 
WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Michael_Jackson> owl:sameAs ?wikidata_concept 
FILTER(regex(str(?wikidata_concept), "www.wikidata.org" ) )} 
LIMIT 100
```

It works fine on [Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fwikidata_concept%20WHERE%20%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3AMichael_Jackson%3E%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fwikidata_concept%20FILTER%28regex%28str%28%3Fwikidata_concept%29%2C%20%22www.wikidata.org%22%20%29%20%29%7D%20LIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20). I get `http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q7215695` as the answer which is correct.

However, when I try to do the same using `SPARQLWrapper` in python, I don't get the above answer (basically the data frame in empty).

My python code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql")
item = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Michael_Jackson"
sparql.setQuery(f"SELECT distinct ?wikidata_concept WHERE {{<{item}> owl:sameAs ?wikidata_concept FILTER(regex(str(?wikidata_concept), \"www.wikidata.org\" ) )}} LIMIT 100")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
print(results)
results_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(results['results']['bindings'])
print(results_df)
```

Please let me know where I am making things wrong. I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: in the code you used DBpedia Live endpoint, the web GUI in your link is the normal DBpedia endpoint ...

Comment: I also don't see why you used the category `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Michael_Jackson` instead of the entity itself, i.e.  `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson` which indeed would work

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot for the valuable comments. I tried `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson` However, it did not work. When I changed to `SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")` it worked. Thanks a lot :) Just wondering what is the difference between `live` and `normal` dbpedia. What do you recommend for industry level applications? Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: The DBpedia Live endpoint is more or less in sync with Wikipedia, i.e. changes to Wikipedia will be reflected in DBpedia Live in a few minutes (or maybe a bit longer). The "normal" DBpedia endpoint contains just a dump of Wikipedia transformed to RDF and is usually outdated. I mean, look at https://wiki.dbpedia.org/develop/datasets - the latest dataset is from 2016 ... not sure if they ever loaded a new dump and forget to upload it to their web page.

Comment: using `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson` also works on DBpedia Live - it's just your filter which doesn't work as they link to different Wikidata URI style (without `www`): See `SELECT distinct ?wikidata_concept 
WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson> owl:sameAs ?wikidata_concept 
} 
LIMIT 100`

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot. I found the details that you have posted very useful. As you have mentioned, it seems like the problem is with my query. When I ran the command `SELECT distinct ?wikidata_concept WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson> owl:sameAs ?wikidata_concept } LIMIT 100` It returns all the `owl:sameas`. I only want its wikidata entry. Is there a way to change my query using a diffrent `FILTER`. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Watch the URIs and then look at your filters. I'm sure you will figure out why it doesn't match the regex? And also how to change the filter

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot. Sure, I will spend some time in changing my filter. BTW just curious why DBpedia entities such as `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Word2vec` do not contain any `owl:sameas` in  the `live` version. Basically this query does not return anything at all: `SELECT distinct ?wikidata_concept WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson> owl:sameAs ?wikidata_concept } LIMIT 100` :)

Comment: your last query does return something ...

Comment: and regarding the Live version, look at `http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Word2vec` in the browser. There is no such data. And no, I don't know. I'm not responsible for DBpedia nor working for the project. Ask on their mailing list, there is a lot of missing data currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBpedia has 2 versions. So, the reason why I got two results is that I am using different versions in the two approaches.

Changing `sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql")` to `sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")` solved my issue. So, I am using the same dbpedia version in the query editor and in my python code.